# in Editable Grid how to insert all records at a time to DB?

Tags: asp.net

By using editable grid i need to add multiple records.

if suppose added one record it can be show in grid without interaction to db same as he can edit and delete the added records without interaction to db after finalize the all records then click OK button then all records need to add to DB.

Please ,tell me how to acheive this.

Any other possible way for this.

Any sample code projects please tell me?

Answer (score 1):

You can loop through GridViewRows like this,

```
foreach (GridViewRow gv GridView1.Rows)
{
  //Find control and Update Query goes here
}
```

find your TextBox using **FindControl** method like this

```
TextBox txt1 = (TextBox)gv.FindControl("TextBox1");
```

Now, Within loop use **txt1.Text** value and update your DB with each record

hope this'll help you